# iOS Auto Layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have the following view controller that I want to look great on all iPhones,  I have been trying for hours and hours with the auto layout with no luck.  The cats are buttons with the cat image as a background to the button.  Can somebody tell me what should I do?

UPDATE: My goal is that there size adapts to the different iPhone screen sizes and they remain positioned this way.  I tried setting 4 constraints from the 4 sides while not locking the width and the height and it looks bad. Help, please?

This is the image
[image: This is the image]

Comment: you should explain what constraints you have and where you see problems with them

Comment: I'd suggest panic. What is the exact problem? Right now it's hard to help you, because I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @FreeNickname & Wain I have just updated the question with the details you asked for. Please help me :(

Comment: Can you share your xib file. I'll fix it and give it to you

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use size class for the different size screen with autolayout . It will resolve you problem.

Comment: Thanks, @himanshu! I tried setting the width to compact and the height to regular but still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiplier property of autolayout constraints to achieve this. Please share your xib file